# Email Notice to User When Newsfeed is Posted

Tags: workflow, newsfeed

I want to send an email to one or more users when a newsfeed is posted on a specific site.  I have used examples to create the site workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2013.  I have saved and published the workflow but in testing using myself as the user I am not receiving email notices.  I followed the instructions in one of answers - "Generating an email alert for new post in site feed" but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Confirm if SMTP is configured properly

Answer (score 0):

- on list workflow settings check if "Creating a new item will start this workflow" is checked?
- Check if Configure outgoing e-mail settings is configured?